# Passing an element of array to a function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to pass to a function an element of an array of structs. But I still can't.

Person is a nested struct.

```
//define Address structure
struct Address
{
    string Street;
    string City;
    string PostalCode;
};

//define Person structure
struct Person
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
    float Salary;
    struct Address Address;
};

// How I invoque the function
cout << "Address: " << ConcateAddress(persons[i].Address) << endl;


// Return a concatenated string with completed address of persion
string ConcateAddress(struct Address address)
{    
    string adressFinal=  address.Street + " " + address.PostalCode;
    if(!address.City.empty()){
        adressFinal = adressFinal + ", "+ address.City;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things. First, there's no `main()` function, so you can't execute anything. Second, the function `ConcateAddress` needs to be declared before you use it.

Comment: The problem you are having is not readily apparent from the code snippets you have posted. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using a `std::array` or a `std::vector` rather than a raw C-style array will make your life easier.

Comment: Unrelated: You may find passing by reference useful. Compilers are smart (and getting smarter. Soon they will rule the universe! Muhuhahahahahaha!) and may take advantage of `address` not being modified within `ConcateAddress` to eliminate the copying that would normally result from `address` being passed by value. Nested structure generally refers to a  structure defined within another structure, not a structure containing another structure.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a return statement at the end of your function definition. You are successfully passing the element of array to the function, but your function does not return any value.

```
string ConcateAddress(struct Address address)
{    
    string adressFinal=  address.Street + " " + address.PostalCode;
     if(!address.City.empty()){
          adressFinal = adressFinal + ", "+ address.City;
     }
    return adressFinal;    //return statement
}
```